# Best way to refactor such a dummy code with help of Haskell's standard libraries?

Tags: haskell, refactoring

I am currently working with quite dirty project written in Haskell.
It contains lots of code like:

```
try_parse_parameters (p:ps) kvps options = 
        let maybeKvp = try_parse_kvp p 
        in
          if isJust maybeKvp 
            then try_parse_parameters ps ((fromJust maybeKvp) : kvps) options
            else 
              let maybeOption = try_parse_option p
              in 
                if isJust maybeOption
                  then try_parse_parameters ps kvps ((fromJust maybeOption) : options)
                  else try_parse_parameters ps kvps options
```

Thus, my questions is: is there some **standard** method(s) to deal with such a situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also handle more than one case with pattern matching, avoiding the [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)).

```
try_parse_parameters (p:ps) kvps options = 
    case (try_parse_kvp p, try_parse_option p) of
      (Just k, _)       -> try_parse_parameters ps (k : kvps) options
      (Nothing, Just o) -> try_parse_parameters ps kvps (o : options)
      (Nothing, Nothing)-> try_parse_parameters ps kvps options
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, what you're looking for is called *pattern matching*, and you can't really write haskell without it. Here's the most straightforward adaptation of your code:

```
try_parse_parameters (p:ps) kvps options = 
    case try_parse_kvp p of
      Just kvp -> try_parse_parameters ps (kvp : kvps) options
      Nothing -> 
        case try_parse_option p of
          Just o -> try_parse_parameters ps kvps (o : options)
          Nothing -> try_parse_parameters ps kvps options
```

From here there are a lot of things you might improve, now or later as you learn more haskell:

- I would really suggest using CamelCase, which is standard but also more readable because you can easily distinguish functions from their arguments
- you're doing a *fold* over the list. You could use `foldr` to factor out the recursion and make it more clear to people reading your code what it does (and what it can't do; i.e. making it easier to reason about)
- add a type signature, handle the empty list case, maybe other issues
- You might find that the `Alternative` class is helpful, or using a monadic fold perhaps if you want the entire computation to fail if any of the parses fail completely